# Government Bodies and Space Exploration

Tags: rockets

My question is rather a opinion based one.

Why does Government Space Agencies (all) not run behind Reusable Launch Vehicles when they know slight hike in budget can significantly contribute to Cut High Costs on Launch?

If development of indigenous technologies takes time then WHY IS TRANSFER OF TECHNOLOGY not an option?

Comment: Are you asking why "rocket technology, space launch, command/control type technology" is not being shared / collaboration to reduce overall total mission costs ? There is a lot more collaborative works now ( I.S.S and predecessors for instance) but suspect competition effects by human nature itself go back to the sixties original "moon race" mindset unfortunately.

Comment: Definitely this isn't my question!... Anyways thanks ..though this doesn't fulfill the objective of questioning!

Comment: Re *My question is rather a opinion based one.* That (that a question is opinion based) is in and of itself a standard reason to close a question all across the stack exchange network.

Comment: Re *WHY IS TRANSFER OF TECHNOLOGY not an option?* First things first: USE OF ALL CAPS IS NOT AN OPTION. That said, country A's space exploration technology might well be exactly what country B needs to make its missiles more precise, and who knows if some of those missiles are aimed at country A. This means technology sharing between countries is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does Government Space Agencies (all) not run behind Reusable Launch Vehicles when they know slight hike in budget can significantly contribute to Cut High Costs on Launch?

Politics. This year's legislative assembly has to justify the slight hike in budget, while some future legislative assembly, if anyone, has to answer for the higher future launch costs.

> If development of indigenous technologies takes time then WHY IS TRANSFER OF TECHNOLOGY not an option?

If you're wondering why, specifically, other countries don't license reusable tech from SpaceX, it's because [US law restricts export of technology that could be applied to military missiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations).

More generally, transfer of technology *is* an option; India, for example, was unsuccessful in developing their own liquid rocket engines and so licensed the [Viking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_(rocket_engine)) design from France and adapted it as [Vikas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikas_(rocket_engine)).